# What does “which” refer to in 'an aspect of the article which we think is positive'?

Tags: conjunctions, relative-pronouns, relative-clauses

Question about

> an aspect of the article which we think is positive.

Which noun phrase  are we thinking is positive? Is  *article* positive, or is *an aspect of the article* positive ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It could be either, depending on the context. It would help if you wrote a complete sentence. *An aspect of the article which we think is positive* is a noun phrase, not a sentence.

Comment: the proffessor gave only this headline for raleted  questions to the article. So it is ambigious but in profesor's respect it refers to an aspect of the article. hence i was confused because as far as i know clauses always describe the words which is next to clausal verb.

Comment: The unspecified *preceding* text could give us, say, ***the presentation of** an aspect of the article which we think is positive*, in which case "positive" might refer to the "presentation". That's to say - without more context, *we have no idea* what specific noun phrase the authors think is positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relative clause *which we think is positive* can modify either the noun phrase *the article* or the noun phrase *an aspect of the article*.

If you are talking about one article, then in all likelihood, the clause modifies *an aspect of the article*.

If there are two or more articles under discussion, then it could very well modify *the article*, so that "an aspect of [the article which we think is positive]" is the correct way to parse the phrase. This would be in opposition to, for example, "an aspect of [the article which we think is negative]".

Part of this is going to be dependent on the topic under discussion. Sentences and other clauses are usually discourse dependent regarding their interpretation. Often we can't determine the meaning of a sentence, clause or phrase just by looking at it alone.